# Почему exe файл c pyttsx3 не запускается, а без него все ок?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyttsx3

Сделал небольшую консоль где вводим тест проговаривается с помощью pyttsx3 все работает, но после преобразования в exe командная страка сразу же закрывается.

Comment: Скорее всего, зависимость к pyttsx3 не подхватилась. В файл сборки добавьте руками модуль pyttsx3

Comment: как это сделать ?

Comment: Например, через командную строку, указав скрытый импорт: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22105547/5909792 Либо подправить файл, что генерируется перед сборкой

Comment: как я понял ты говоришь отредактировать spec фал ?

Comment: Да, можно в него добавить: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35605281/5909792