# При запуске скомпилированного файла появляется ошибка docx.opc.exceptions.packagenotfounderror package not found at 'max.docx'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, python-docx

При запуске ярлыка все открывается, но не выполняет функции и выдает ошибку:

[image: ошибка]

Вот ссылка на архив проекта.
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/9SKRW7xBkJj56A

Компилировала через pyinstaller. Не могу понять, почему не находит docx. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Нужно вручную указать тот модуль, т.к. pyinstaller не смог сам его найти. Этот вопрос часто поднимается, недавно уже отвечал на него, посмотрите в комментариях: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1264428/201445

Comment: Прекратите компилировать язык, который не предназначен для этого. Разработчик этого прекрасного модуля для компиляции будет в гробу долго вертеться

Comment: Вбить именно так: 'pyinstaller --hidden-import=max.docx glav.py'? Я попробовала так, но не работает(